# How to access nested html-child elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm using a html-form with nested div-elements with this structure:

```
<form id="form">
    <div id="parentproperties">
        <legend class="itemName">People</legend>
        <br>
        <div id="properties1">
            <legend class="itemName">Name</legend>
            <label class="valueId">JaneDoe</label>
            <br>
            <label class="labelId">Id: </label>
            <input class="inputId">5646543</input>
        </div>
        <div id="properties2">
            <legend class="itemName">Address</legend>
            <label class"valueId">MysteriousStreet</label>
            <br>
            <label class="labelId">Id: </label>
            <input class="inputId">1234</input>
        </div>
        <div id="properties3">
            <legend class="itemName">Country</legend>
            <label class"valueId">SomeCountry</label>
            <br>
            <label class="labelId">Id: </label>
            <input class="inputId">7899542</input>
                    <div id="properties4">
                    <legend class="itemName"></legend>
                    <br>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now I need to access the field with the Id 'valueID' for every 'div' to change a specific value. I've tried several loops but they do not not work properly... Later I've tried to get a particular element directly this way:

```
document.getElementById("properties").childNodes[0].innerHTML;
```

...but I only get the first valueId with value 'JaneDoe'. 
Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: `id`s are supposed to be unique within the document. Use `class` or `data-*` attribute to group elements.

Comment: Use a class instead of an id. id attributes should be unique, they're like addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the current HTML structure needs some attention:

1. Don't use a unique ID more than once. Use classes, `data-` attributes, or unique IDs.
2. Input elements do not have closing tags, they're self-closing `<input />`.

Now, to select the elements you want, you have several options.

1. Give each element a unique ID and select it with

   ```
   document.getElementById('input-1').value('new value');
   ```
2. Or loop through the `input` elements with something like:

   ```
   document.querySelectorAll('.inputId'))
   ```

   which will return a NodeList of all the elements with a class of `inputId`

```js
document.getElementById('input-1').value = "New Value"
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <div>
    <legend id="itemName">People</legend>
    <br>
    <div class="properties">
      <legend class="itemName">Name</legend>
      <label class="valueId">JaneDoe</label>
      <br>
      <label class="labelId">Id: </label>
      <input class="inputId" id="input-1" value="5646543" />
    </div>
    <div class="properties">
      <legend class="itemName">Address</legend>
      <label class="valueId">MysteriousStreet</label>
      <br>
      <label class="labelId">Id: </label>
      <input class="inputId" id="input-2" value="1234" />
    </div>
    <div class="properties">
      <legend class="itemName">Country</legend>
      <label class="valueId">SomeCountry</label>
      <br>
      <label class="labelId">Id: </label>
      <input class="inputId" id="input-2" value="7899542" />
    </div>
    <div id="properties">
      <legend id="itemName"></legend>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Your solution helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`childNodes[0]` selects the first node of all child nodes, so you can use `childNodes[1]`, `childNodes[2]` and so on. As Teemu said, `id`s should be unique, in your case it looks like a good point to use classes.

Answer (score 0):

as @Teemu says in comment `id`s should be unique within the document, instead you could give them some `class="a"`

then you could get all elements by class `document.getElementsByClassName("a")`

Answer (score 0):

Use children instead of childNodes :

```
document.getElementById("properties1").children[0].innerHTML =
```

Also you should use unique id string for element id.

childNodes return a [NodeList object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which also includes textNodes and commentNodes etc. But, children method will only give you [HTMLCollection object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to use class attributes in the place of id attributes.

```html
document.getElementsByClassName("properties")[0].childNotes[0].innerHTML;
```